# From vs For with year

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage

Which is correct / acceptable usage

> I pride myself associated with CompanyX from past 3 years.

OR

> I pride myself associated with CompanyX for past 3 years.

OR something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

> I pride myself *for being* associated with CompanyX **for *the* past 3 years**.

*for* indicates a period of time.

If you were to use *from* (which indicates a starting time), then:

> I pride myself *for being* associated with CompanyX **from 2013 to 2015**.